# HTML elements used for data/news feed in a page?

Tags: html

I would like to design a layout for a html news feed page. I'm imagining the FB newsfeed.

What is the appropriate html elements for displaying iterated data?

Comment: The FB feed uses `<div>` elements, Twitter uses `<li>` elements in an `<ol>` list. Learn how to use the developer console in your web browser, and you can easily check these things yourself! In HTML5 [`<article>`](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/) might make a good candidate, depending on what the feed items contain.

Comment: @leo Alright, so you said FB feed uses <div>, but is this all? I'm asking about the main container that will iterate the data in your html layout. So if it uses <div>, how many div elements are you going to use because as far as I know if you only use one div element, when you iterate data from your server, it's only the last data will be displayed in your div element. That's  why I was asking what is the exact main container that can iterate and display several data in your layout.

Comment: Each post is the FB feed is in a div element, if that's what you are wondering? “[...]because as far as I know if you only use one div element, when you iterate data from your server[...]” I have no idea what this means, can you show us an example of what your problem is? Some server side code?

Comment: I understand that each post is in a div element,no questions about that, but what I'm wondering is what is the main container that loops all the data from your server and display it in your div element as you said as for each post within the entire news feed page. I talked about <table> and <ul><li> before on my first post because I think these two html elements can iterate several data within a div element as per post. What I was simply asking and was wondering is, if there's any other html elements aside from <table> or <li> elements that are being used to iterate all the data from server.

Comment: `ol`, `ul` and `dl` are the possible containers for `li` elements. If you are using `div` elements for the items, you could just put them in another `div` element (like Facebook does).

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about appropriate elements for holding a list of elements in e.g. a new feed. Short answer: **Any [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)**.

There is no `feed` element or similar in HTML, and for instance Facebook and Twitter uses a container `<div>` containing other divs, and Wordpress default themes use a `<div>` container with `<article>` elements. If each item makes for an own, independant piece of information, somthing that would normally be awarded an entry of it's own in an RSS feed, then the article element is probably a good choice, otherwise opt for divs. As for the container element, it depends more on its role on the page, than on its content. It could be a `<div>`, or a `<section>`, or something else.

Depending on your content, it might make sense semantically to use a list. As we are talking about a feed, an enumerated list (`<ol>`) is probably not the best option. That leaves you with either an unordered list, **[`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)**, containing `<li>` elements, or a definition list, **[`<dl>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)** containing pairs of `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags.

Tables should only be used for tabular data, and it is most likely not for your news feed (unless you are really printing data that goes in rows and columns).

If you feel the need for a semantically more accurate markup for you news feed, there is an interesting experiment explained at microformats.org: [h-feed](http://microformats.org/wiki/h-feed). It is implemented with classes:

```
<div class="h-feed">

  <article class="h-entry">
    <h1>An entry</h1>
    <p>And some text</p>
  </article>

  <article class="h-entry">
    <h1>Another entry</h1>
    <p>And some text</p>
  </article>

</div>
```

Comment: I think my question should be what is the best iterator/enumerator element for data feed. I do disagree on some part of your statement that table is not suitable for news feed and should only be used in tabular data.Really?Do we really need to tabulate our data?In short, we can't change the layout for our table because it's intended only for tabular format? On the other hand, <ol> and <ul>, don't they have rows for their lists to enumerate as table does?In short, we can use any of the three enumerator elements as the main container depending on how you layout correct?

Comment: Of course you can make a table look however you want, but the HTML5 spec is quite clear about its intended usage: [The table element represents data with more than one dimension, in the form of a table.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) (As an experiment, try using a table, then close your eyes and navigate through your page using a screen reader!)

Comment: So the best suggestion that you can give is either <ol> and <ul> as the main enumerator that contains all the data to display in the news feed page because twitter uses it? But still you have no clue of what is the main enumerator of FB feed because div element is not the enumerator, its only a container for each post that resides in the main data enumerator of your news feed layout correct?

Comment: @timmack The “main enumerator” that both Twitter and Facebook use is a `<div>`. They have one parent div, containing child divs for each post.

You can very easily check yourself. In Chrome, press `F12`  or `Ctrl Shift-I` to open the developer tools, and inspect the source.

Comment: I checked it, yes I can see on their elements that there are parent div and child divs that each holds corresponding data. No questions about that, but that is not so called enumerator, that is called container. These two have different meaning.I bet you cannot see there what is the exact enumerator whether it uses <ol>,<li> or <table>. Check yourself at Google translate to see the difference between "enumerator" and "container".

Comment: I think you are probably talking about the backend here (`.NET`?), not about the HTML?

Comment: It could have been both. Let's say I used parent div and child div without enumerator/iterator like <ol><ul> or <table>. If I used foreach loop unto them expecting bunch of data from your database without those three (<ol><ul> or <table>). Can you imagine what is your output?

Comment: ”foreach loop”? Are you talking about a PHP script? Can you edit your post to show us the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62976/discussion-between-leo-and-timmack).

Comment: No, I'm not using php. I'm a .Net guy,are you familiar with Razor View engine in ASP.Net MVC? You can make looping there on your html elements like <table>,etc.You've just edited my post which made it shorter. I don't have a code to show yet coz Im still planning out my entire layout that's why I bring up this topic here. Sure, we can continue this discussion in the chat session. Just ping me here when you're ready.

Comment: I just replied to you in the chat session. Please see my additional questions. Thanks

Comment: Ok, your question is no longer about html, but about .NET then! You might want to rephrase it and add the appropriate tags, or post an entirely new question, to make it more likely that someone who knows .NET finds it!

Comment: Leo what tools are you working with? .Net,php,java,python or perl,etc.? just curious...

Comment: Have you followed it from my first post what was it all about?